# How to use Output binding component outside of the template in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, angularjs-controller, angularjs-components

in the `SAVE Button` I want to use the `param` to enable or disable button, using the function from the component, ex. If the input field has 7 characters then return `true` and enable the save button. But now I'm stuck and I cannot use the `param` outside of the `test-component template`.

The structure can be like this:
1. a function inside the `testComponent.js` which check the length of input string
2. if length is bigger than 6 then pass the `true` to the `param` variable
3. then enable the `save button` which is outside of the `testComponent.js`

Here is also the **[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/ThhcfuksuYWhsLk91emf?p=preview)**

Already in the snippet the button is hard coded.

```js
    angular
        .module('client', [])
        .component('testComponent', {
            template: '<h1>{{$ctrl.param}}</h1>',
            controller: function() {
                // this.param = '123';
            },
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindings: {
                param: '@'
            }
        })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>AngularJS Example</title>

    <!-- AngularJS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="client">
    Test
    <test-component param=true>  </test-component>

    <button ng-disabled="true">Save</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```